# I'm stucked in this ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

result:
[image]

This ajax can't give me a result. I'm struggling with this issue. I don't know why and I couldn't find where is the mistake. I was tried another ajax and it works, but i don't know with this one. How's this? somebody help me, thanks.

ztest1.php:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style></style>

    <script>
    function checkemail() {
        var status = document.getElementById("emailudahada");
        var u = document.getElementById("email").value;
        if (u != "") {
            document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            status.innerHTML = "<img src='/img/loading.GIF'></img>";
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ztest2.php',
                type: "POST",

                data: ({
                    email: u,
                    cekemailsignup: 'yes'
                }),
                success: function(result) {
                    status.innerHTML = result['result'] + "," + result['cekemailsignup'] + "," + result['email'];
                }
            });
        } else {
            document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='emailudahada'></div>
    <input type='text' id='email' onblur='checkemail()'></input>
</body>

</html>
```

ztest2.php:

```
<?php
    include('ckcon.php');

    $cekemailsignup=isset($_REQUEST['cekemailsignup'])?$_REQUEST['cekemailsignup']:null;
    if($cekemailsignup=='yes'){
        $email=isset($_REQUEST['email'])?$_REQUEST['email']:null;
        $q=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(email) AS ce FROM t_un WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
        $f=mysql_fetch_object($q);
        $ce=$f->ce;
        if($email==null){
            $result="<img src='/img/xred.png'></img> <font color='red'>Cant be null value</font>";
        }
        if(strlen($email) < 4){
            $result="<img src='/img/xred.png'></img> <font color='red'>4 digit at minimum</font>";
        }
        if(is_numeric($email[0])){
            $result="<img src='/img/xred.png'></img> <font color='red'>1st character must be letter</font>";
        }
        if($ce<>0){
            //$result="<img src='/img/xred.png'></img> <font color='red'><strong>".$email."</strong> is taken</font>";
            $result="kampret lu";
        }
        echo "
            cekemailsignup=$cekemailsignup<br>
            email=$email<br>
            ce=$ce<br>
            result=$result<br>
        ";
        $ar = array(
                    'result' => $result,
                    'cekemailsignup' => $cekemailsignup,
                    'email' => $email
                    );
        echo json_encode($ar);
    }
?>
```

Comment: `echo "
           cekemailsignup=$cekemailsignup<br>
            email=$email<br>
            ce=$ce<br>
            result=$result<br>
        ";` why do you have this?remove this and try again

Comment: Yes @pekka is right. Remove that

Comment: It still doesn't worked

Comment: you are right Pekka and Aldrin27, but not perfect enough, i run your suggest, i delete an echo then run Karan and Tushar  suggest, and it worked now. Thank you every one, you are all the best friend for me.

Comment: Why did i get a downvote? I'm just asked, not a spammer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is changed js function

```
<script>
function checkemail() {
    var status = document.getElementById("emailudahada");
    var u = document.getElementById("email").value;
    if (u != "") {
        document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        status.innerHTML = "<img src='/img/loading.GIF'></img>";
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ztest2.php',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json", //need to tell that response will as json
            data: ({
                email: u,
                cekemailsignup: 'yes'
            }),
            success: function(result) {
                status.innerHTML = result.result + "," + result.cekemailsignup. + "," + result.email;
            }
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I run your suggest, i delete an echo (Pekka and Aldrin27 suggest), and it worked now. Thank you every one, you are all the best friend of me.

Comment: please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)

Answer (score 1):

`result` is **string**, to use it like object you need to parse it to JSON.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
```

You can also set `dataType: 'json',` in the `$.ajax` configuration options to set it by default and then you don't need to parse the response, it can be directly used.

As jQuery is included on page, use it for DOM manipulation.

Complete Code:

```
$('#email').on('blur', function() {
  var $status = $('#emailudahada');
  email = $.trim($(this).val());

  if (email) {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
    $status.html('<img src=\'/img/loading.GIF\'></img>');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/ztest2.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',

      data: ({
        email: email,
        cekemailsignup: 'yes'
      }),
      success: function(result) {
        $status.html(result.result + ',' + result.cekemailsignup. + ',' + result.email);
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'white');
  }
});
```

Comment: please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)

Answer (score 1):

HTML File

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    </style>
    <script>
    function checkemail(){
        var status = document.getElementById("emailudahada");
        var u = document.getElementById("email").value;
        if(u != ""){
            document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            status.innerHTML = "<img src='/img/loading.GIF'></img>";
            $.ajax({
                url: '/ztest2.php',
                type: "POST",

                data: ({
                     email: u,
                     cekemailsignup: 'yes'
                }),
                success : 
                function(result2){
                 var result = JSON.parse(result2);
                    status.innerHTML=result['result']+","+result['cekemailsignup']+","+result['email'];
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            document.getElementById("email").style.backgroundColor = "white";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='emailudahada'></div>
    <input type='text' id='email' onblur='checkemail()'></input>
</body>
```

PHP file (ztest2.php)

```html
<?php
    $ar = array(
                    'result' => "123",
                    'cekemailsignup' => "true",
                    'email' => "ririnputrian@gmail.com"
                    );
        echo json_encode($ar);
?>
```

Comment: Hatur Nuhun kang Indra, tapi udah dijawab ama kang Karan. Tapi tenang, ane +1 karena sebangsa dan setanah air. :D

Comment: Kang @Indra, bantuin lagi dong kang [disini](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system), trims kang.